# How can implement full code for alert rate and view app store

Tags: ios, swift

As you may have seen in some apps an alert pops up asking the user to rate the app in itunes and usually the alternatives you get to choose from is something like: Sure which opens the rate page for the app. The second option is No Thanks which closes the alert and the third option usually is maybe later which displays the alert later.

I was wondering how to do this. I want the alert to be displayed after say the app has launched 20 times if that would be possible.

please sure the code by swift 2
Thanks alot for your response.

when i used this code, its show me always alert even when i click on "No Thanks"

```
func showRateMe() {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rate Us", message: "Thanks for using <APP NAME>", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rate <APP NAME>", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=<iTUNES CONNECT APP ID>")!)
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No Thanks", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "neverRate")
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe Later", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()showRateMe()}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

know, when i using this code, the alert not appear at all

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var iMinSessions = 3
var iTryAgainSessions = 6



func viewDidAppear(){
    showRateMe()
}
func showRateMe() {
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rate Us", message: "Thanks for using <APP NAME>", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rate <APP NAME>", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=<iTUNES CONNECT APP ID>")!)
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No Thanks", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "neverRate")
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe Later", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func rateMe() {
    var neverRate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("neverRate")
    var numLaunches = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("numLaunches") + 1

    if (!neverRate && (numLaunches == iMinSessions || numLaunches >= (iMinSessions + iTryAgainSessions + 1)))
    {
        showRateMe()
        numLaunches = iMinSessions + 1
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(numLaunches, forKey: "numLaunches")
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see any complex task to implement this. What did you try and where did you have a problem?

Comment: this is my code in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that worked for me:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var iMinSessions = 3
var iTryAgainSessions = 2


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    rateMe()
}

func showRateMe() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rate Us", message: "Thanks for using <APP NAME>", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rate <APP NAME>", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=<iTUNES CONNECT APP ID>")!)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"didRate")
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No Thanks", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey:"didRate")
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Maybe Later", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func rateMe() {
    let didRate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("didRate")

    let numLaunches = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("numLaunches") + 1
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(numLaunches, forKey: "numLaunches")

    if !didRate && (numLaunches == iMinSessions ||
                    numLaunches > iMinSessions && (numLaunches - iMinSessions) % iTryAgainSessions == 0 )
    {
        showRateMe()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

What I've changed:
The numbers for iMinSessions and iTryAgainSessions to 2 and 3, because I'm not patient!

I changed  viewDidAppear
: receives a bool, is overriden (that was perhaps your problem)
I called rateMe, and not swowRateMe

In showRateMe, I change the boolean when the button "Rate" or the button "No thanks" is clicked (I think that was the goal). Please note that the OpenURL doesn't work for me.

In rateme, I changed the boolean name for didRate (because it is false at the beginning, and becomes true when rated)

I changed the test, so that

- App not rated and

  - numLaunches = initial minimum or
  - numLauches > initial minimum, and the number of lauches since initial minimum is a multiple of iTryAgainSessions: with my numbers: when numLauches = 3 + 2 or numLauches = 3 + 2 + 2, or numLaunches = 3 + 2 + 2 + 2, ....

I hope I was understandable.

Comment: yes, finally.. its work fine, thanks a lot for excellent explain, and about theOpenURL also work with me, but i have change on the link "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/id=<YOUR ID APP>"

Comment: this code i have searched about it many days, thank you again for your responce